# Counting the common indices shared between columns of a dataframe containing only binary values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a dataframe containing binary values as:

```
     A    B    C    D
a    1    0    0    0
b    0    1    1    0
c    1    1    0    1
d    0    0    1    1
e    1    1    1    1
f    1    0    0    1
```

I'd like to count the number of common indices shared between the pair of columns in the dataframe
as shown below. What is the most efficient way to do so in R ?

```
     A    B    C    D
A    -    2    1    3
B    2    -    2    2
C    1    2    -    2
D    3    2    2    -
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are after

```
> `diag<-`(crossprod(as.matrix(df)),NA)
   A  B  C  D
A NA  2  1  3
B  2 NA  2  2
C  1  2 NA  2
D  3  2  2 NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), B = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), C = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), D = c(0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", "b", "c",
"d", "e", "f"))
```

Comment: A slight changed option `tcrossprod(t(df)) * NA^(diag(ncol(df)))`